# How to prevent an async method form being called twice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

I have an app that is keeping track of some data every .01 seconds. When the data (NSArray) count reaches 50 items I want to send this to the server asynchronously. The problem is that by the time the call returns from the server I will have had another 20 plots or more. But the other issue is that method call that gets called when it hits 50 will get called when its 51, 52, 53, etc...

Now what I can do is flush the original array so that the next 20 go into it while I send up the original 50, but my question is what if the data points come quickly at I get 50 more before the first call to the server returns?

My question is what is the best way to handle this? Maybe some sort of async call factory? So every time I hit 50 I flush the array and send the 50 points to some async factory that creates an async object that know how to send up its own data?

1-50 > send to factory that creates a delegate object that is responsible for sending to server.
2-50 send to factory that creates a delegate object that is responsible for sending to server.
etc....

This would work, but what if something goes wrong and in the delegates. How to reconcile the points that failed to make it to the server? Is there a design pattern that is used for this type of problem?

Comment: How are you sending to the server asynchronously?  Show us some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is not preventing async method being called twice. It's scheduling your task. You are on the right track on flushing the 50 objects. The problem is NSArray is not a thread safe object, sharing the same NSArray object with multiple concurrent methods is not safe. For the method that's recording the data, it should has its own local buffer. Once the local buffer reaches 50, it send the delegate callback with a new array with the 50 objects (not a copy), and at that point, it's safe for the recording method to clear its buffer.

For your Sender class, it should have a pendingQueue array which is a collection of your data that are waiting to be sent to server, and you can handle your error in this class easily. Make sure to serialize when you're addingObjects or removeObject in the pendingQueue to avoid threading problem.

So something like this should work. (You will need a main method that set up these objects and delegate. Also the example omits the initialization.)

```
@protocol RecorderDelegate

 - (void)recorderDidReachDataPoint:(NSArray *)data;

@end

@interface Recorder()

@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate

 - (void)recordTaskWithProgressHandler
{
    NSMutableArray *buffer = [NSMutableArray array];
    while ( ...pause for 0.01 second or whatever )
    {
        // record your task using buffer
        // ...
        if (buffer.count == 50)
        {
            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelecter:@selector(recorderDidReachDataPoint:)])
            {
                [self.delegate recorderDidReachDataPoint:[NSArray arrayWithArray:buffer]];
            }
            [buffer removeAllObjects];
        }
    }
}
@end


@interface Sender ()<RecorderDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *pendingQueue;

 - (void)sendToServer
{
    // Do your async method.
    // once the data is successfully uploaded remove the object from pendingQueue
    // if failed, you can either retry or append them to the end of pendingQueue to try later
}

// delegate
 - (void)recorderDidReachDataPoint:(NSArray *)data
{
    [self.pendingQueue addObjectsFromArray:data];
    [self sendToServer];
}
```

Comment: Makes sense but what does this line mean?  while ( ...pause for 0.01 second or whatever )

Comment: It just means whichever way you want. I wasn't sure how you were keeping track of data every .01 second, so that was just a random guess. Maybe you could have a variable to stop tracking in your while loop or a method that pause for .01 second and return true/YES or even something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to handle this would be to use some kind of queue for the request.

I can recommend [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) which is a framework for handling network requests. It will detect if the request fails and you can send it again.

You can find lots of tutorials and guides how to handle requests with the framework and how to use the queues.

Comment: -1 for recommending ASI. Even the author says not to use it any more.

Comment: Didn't know that, it has been working for me so far. Removed the reference.

Comment: I'm trying to remove the downvote but it won't let me, perhaps because you edited it so soon after posting. I'll file a bug, but in the meantime I'll edit it slightly so I can change my vote